# how to use pandas to create correlation matrix of multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: python, r, matrix, pandas, statsmodels

In R, we could create the correlation matrix like this:

```
makecov <- function(rho,n) {
    m <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
    m <- ifelse(row(m)==col(m),1,rho)
    return(m)
}
```

As we know the correlation,the result would be:

```
makecov(0.2,3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  1.0  0.2  0.2
#[2,]  0.2  1.0  0.2
#[3,]  0.2  0.2  1.0
```

But in pandas,how could we create the same matrix efficiently?
Here is my solution:

```
def makecov(rho,n):
    m=[rho/2]*n*n
    m=np.array(m).reshape([n,n])
    return m+m.T-np.diag([rho]*n)+np.diag([1]*n)
```

And the result would be:

```
In [21]:makecov(0.2,3)
Out[21]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.2,  1. ,  0.2],
       [ 0.2,  0.2,  1. ]])
```

Is there some more elegant ways to do that with pandas?

Comment: your r function could just be `\`diag<-\`(matrix(.2, 3, 3), 1)`

Comment: I'm reading The Art of R Programming.The R function is just from the book.And I try to rewrite this R function with pandas.But your comment is pretty well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could do

```
def makecov(rho, n):
    out = numpy.eye(n) + rho
    numpy.fill_diagonal(out, 1)
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks! It is faster and cleaner! My resolution 10000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 µs per loop,you did faster 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.82 µs per loop
THS

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using numpy's covariance matrix method instead: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Pandas in my experience is better used for data cleaning and whatnot. I usually let numpy do the heavy statistical lifting.